# how can I do symbolic differentiation for a complicated function using R

Tags: r

I need to differentiate a function that results from matrix and vector multiplication using (D) function in R but each time the result is zero.
here is my code:

```
f1=function(tt){
  u=cbind(cos(tt),sin(tt))
  a=drop((u)%*%solve(var.cov)%*%t(u))
  b=drop((u)%*%solve(var.cov)%*%(mu))
  c=drop(-0.5*t(mu)%*%solve(var.cov)%*%mu)
  d=drop(b/sqrt(a))
  aa=(1/(2*pi*a*sqrt(det(var.cov))))*exp(c)*(1+((d*pnorm(d))/dnorm(d)))
  return(aa)
}
D(expression(f1),"var.cov")
```

I need to get the derivative with respect to the matrix (var.cov).
I do not knowthe reason of that error . 
Is there a package in R that is designed for differentiation ??????
thank you

Comment: Since `var.cov` is not a parameter of `f1` you are differentiating a constant and are correctly getting a 0. Also, the description in `help("D")` says "Compute derivatives of **simple** expressions" (emphasis mine). Even if you do `D(quote((1/(2*pi*a*sqrt(det(var.cov))))*exp(c)*(1+((d*pnorm(d))/dnorm(d)))),"var.cov")` you'll get an error telling you that `D` can't deal with `det`.

Comment: thanks alot for your reply. Is there another function in R for differentiating complicated expressions?

Comment: R is not a computer algebra system. You can interface with one (see the Ryacas package).